# Complex Skew-Symmetric Matrices, Diagonalisibility Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that Real Skew-Symmetric matrices are diagonalisable over Complex field, need not to be over Real field.
But, I am not getting breakthrough of whether Complex Skew-Symmetric matrices are always diagonalisable over Complex filed? If anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Complex skew-symmetric matrices are not necessarily diagonalizable. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3500868/81360) for an example of a skew-symmetric matrix that fails to be diagonalizable.

In particular: for $n = 3$, we can proceed as follows. Define
$$
X = \pmatrix{\frac{1 - i}2 & 0 & \frac{1+i}{2}\\
0 & i & 0\\\frac{1+i}{2} & 0 & \frac{1-i}{2}},
$$
which is a symmetric matrix that satisfies $X^4 = I$. Define $J$ to be the Jordan matrix
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}.
$$
We can show that $XJX^{-1}$ is skew-symmetric, but it is not diagonalizable because it is similar to $J$. In particular, we find that
$$
A = XJX^{-1} = \frac 12 \pmatrix{0 & -1- i & 0\\1+ i & 0 & -1+ i\\0 & 1- i & 0}
$$
is skew-symmetric and non-diagonalizable.

On the other hand, it is true that [skew-Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix) matrices are necessarily diagonalizable as a consequence of the spectral theorem for normal matrices.

Comment: I am unable to find that example in this attached post by you Ben Grossmann. Can you help me plz?

Comment: Thank you! Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome. I've also written the matrix out in full in case you find that helpful. In fact, we can get rid of the $\frac 12$ in front to come up with another valid counterexample.

Comment: Thanks a ton!